# Can't update/ download apps without a card

Tags: iphone

I have a debit card and I've used it to buy items on the App Store. Now it's not accepting the debit card anymore and demands a new card to buy/update apps.

Comment: And this is an actual Apple-branded iPhone, not an Android, correct?

Comment: Has the card expired?

Answer (score 1):

Debit cards are no longer accepted in the iTunes Store, it seems.

The available payment methods vary by country. You can typically use these methods:

- Credit cards
- Content codes
- Store credit, including iTunes Store Gift Cards, Gift Certificates, and Allowances
- ClickandBuy
- PayEase
- PayPal
- UnionPay (requires SMS PIN for setup)

So if you can use PayPal as payment type in the iTunes store. Open a PayPal account, hook up your debit card. And you up and running again.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202631

Answer (score 0):

Please check the (usually) free phone support - they will help you quickly and can tell you about why this happens. Happened to me - wouldn't take my cc card.
Account was flagged, flag got removed within 20 sec - continue to the app store